# How to print Android instrumented test result SUCCESS log in console without verbose info?

Tags: android, gradle, testing, logging, instrumented-test

I have wrote some UI test and run `./gradlew clean connectedAndroidTest --stacktrace` on my command line, what my problem is using `--stacktrace` only shows SKIPPED and FAILED test result, after my research, if I would like to show SUCCESS that I need to use `--info`, but --info show too much info which I don't really need. Is there any better way to approach this? thanks in advance.

My gradle version: 8.0
Android Gradle Plugin: 8.0.2